# PHP - Two directories up doesn't seem to work

Tags: php

I have a problem concerning direcotries. I need to include a file in my php script, and that file is in another folder than my script. By itself, that isn't a problem, I just go a directory up using ../ and work my way to the file. Then the problem is occuring when my script is two folders deep and I use ../../ and I will get an error. Here is my relevant code:

`<?php
        $rootdir = "../../";
 ?>`

Which is followed later by:

```
<?php
    include($rootdir . "style/header.inc.php");

    include($rootdir . "style/navigation.inc.php");
?>
```

and the file itself is located in root\projects\TWPWeb\ and the file I am trying to include is located in root\style\

Strange thing is that my .css file is located in the exact same folder and gets accessed in the exact same way and does work, while include doesn't.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $rootdir ?>style/style.css">
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `include(__DIR__."/../../style/header.inc.php");`

Comment: What error do you get? Could be a permission thing, you usually do not want your assets to be executed as php due to security measurements

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` would serve you well here instead of guessing at the path

Comment: Why not use an absolute path for $rootdir?

Comment: @aynber as I'm hosting the server on a public server, using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will throw an _Operation not permitted_ error. @gskema I tried your method, got the same error as I originally got.

Comment: @gskema never mind, I figured why it doesn't work. `__DIR__` has only been included in PHP 5.3.0. The server I'm hosting my website on only supports PHP 5.2.